# react: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: react-native, npm

I am a newbie to react and I hurdled upon this error while installing the react-native app using the npm. I am the admin on the machine

*unable to get local issuer certificate*

OS- windows 10
npm version: 5.6.*

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to run the below command

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Hope this helps

Comment: don't do this unless you are ok with possible fake sites